# .NET Claim in three namespaces

Tags: .net, wif, claims-based-identity

Now this is odd. After completing some research on claims based solutions in .NET, found that different authors refer to different classes in .NET namespace when actually speaking on the same matter. Claim class (not to mention other Identity, Principal, Manager, Helper classes around) is defined in 3 different namespaces.

It is clear that WIF is separate add-on for .NET 3.5 and 4.0 and that it is rewritten and made part of core in 4.5. However it could really help to have clear directions on what class to use for new projects (so that port to 4.5 after could be easier). Does anybody else have more info on the subject?

1st link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms572956(v=vs.110) (System.IdentityModel.Claims namespace)

2nd: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claim.aspx (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims)

3rd: (System.Security.Claims.Claim)

Comment: Well, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`, for example, have the same name; but they're not the same thing.

Comment: If you have a MSDN subscription you can raise a support ticket or ask a question. But my best bet is that it will be the 3rd one if its moved to core . Same thing happend to Atlas (finally .NET AJAX) framework.

Answer (score 32):

For anyone still looking for a definitive answer to this, MSDN has the following information on it's [System.IdentityModel.Claims Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page...

> The System.IdentityModel.Claims namespace contains classes that
> implement the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) claims-based
> identity authorization model. This model includes the Claim class and
> the ClaimSet class.
>
> Beginning with .NET Framework 4.5 and the
> integration of Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) into the .NET
> Framework, the WCF claims-based identity model has been superseded by
> WIF. WIF provides a claims-based identity object model that can be
> used to provide authentication and authorization across several
> Microsoft product stacks, including the CLR, WCF, and ASP.NET. The WIF
> classes that represent claims, claim types, and identities and
> principals that are based on claims are contained in the
> **System.Security.Claims** namespace. **Beginning with .NET 4.5, these
> classes should be used instead of those in the
> System.IdentityModel.Claims namespace.**

Comment: +1 for the quote that says **...these classes should be used instead of those in the System.IdentityModel.Claims namespace.**

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's answer appears to be: "WIF classes are now spread across various assemblies, the main ones being `System.Security.Claims`, `System.IdentityModel`, and `System.IdentityModel.Services`. `System.Security.Claims` contains the new `ClaimsPrincipal` and `ClaimsIdentity` classes (*see below*). All principals in .NET now derive from `ClaimsPrincipal`. The classes from `Microsoft.IdentityModel` in **WIF 1.0** have been spread mainly across `System.IdentityModel` (*pipeline, WCF integration*) and `System.IdentityModel.Services` (*support for WS-Federation, session management*). Those changes are reflected on the configuration sections as well."

Answer (score 5):

`System.IdentityModel.Claims` is part of WCF/.Net 3.0

`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims` extends `System.IdentityModel.Claims` and is the Windows Identity Foundation class.

`System.Security.Claims` is the .Net 4.5 version.

So if you're writing using `WIF`, you should use `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims`.