# IdentityModel .Net 4.5 Claim vs .Net 4.6 Claim

Tags: .net, authorization, claims-based-identity, claims, .net-4.6

`Claim`s used to have the following *properties* in *.Net 4.5*:

- `ClaimType`: Gets the claim type of the claim.
- `Issuer`:    Gets the issuer of the claim.
- `OriginalIssuer`:    Gets the original issuer of the claim.
- `Properties`:    Gets the properties that are name-value pairs.
- `Subject`:   Gets the subject of the claim.
- `Value`: Gets the value of the claim.
- `ValueType`: Gets the value type of the claim.

It seems that there are new `Claim`s now in *.Net 4.6* with the following *properties*:

- `ClaimType`: Gets the type of the claim.
- `DefaultComparer`:   Gets an object that can compare two Claim objects for equality.
- `Resource`:  Gets the resource with which this Claim object is associated.
- `Right`: A string representation of a uniform resource identifier (URI) that specifies the right associated with this Claim object.
- `System`:    A pre-defined claim that represents the system entity.

Are they both just different representations of the same concept of *claim* in the concept of `claims-based-identity`?

Or the whole concept has changed?

---

To be more exact, I would like to consider the following authoriZation data:

- UserData: `UserId = "5"`;
- ResourceData: `ResourceName = "Book"`;
- ActionData: `ActionName = "ViewContents"`;
- EnvironmentData: `SystemLanguage = "English"`.

As far as I understand, this data can be represented by 4 different old-style *claims*. And this is clear for me how it's possible to create them.

How should this data be correctly represented by the new *claims*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for misleading question.

The first claim from the question (with 7 properties) is the new one. It exists since .Net 4.5. It is from `System.Security.Claims` namespace.

The second claim from the question (with 5 properties) is another claim, which exists since .Net 3.0. It is from `System.IdentityModel.Claims` namespace.

I think that what is needed for the situation in the question is the claim with 7 properties, the first one from `System.Security.Claims`.

EDIT:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21701912/2772330) answer is a good justification.